# finding the framework of a cocoa modules

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I just followed a tutorial https://medium.com/@PyBaig/build-your-own-cocoa-touch-frameworks-in-swift-d4ea3d1f9ca3 for creating your own cocoa touch framework. There is one step where you need to right click a framework and it shows in finder, but it is not working for me. I can right click any other file and show in finder just fine. Any suggestions on how to find the framework file for dragging into another project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well according to [some apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html) I found:

> Note: The standard locations for frameworks are the
>   /System/Library/Frameworks directory and the /Library/Frameworks
>   directory on the local system.

If it isn't in those directories, it is probably some custom path that would be specified on the CC line in the build output, and if you were really hard up, you could click the diff editor on the Xcode project and search for `something.Framework`, where `something` is the framework you are looking for.

... it is also possible that it is a framework that is build by a sub-project, and for whatever reason, it haven't been built yet.

Comment: Right after I saw your post, the right clicking to reveal started working. Your logic to finding the framework does make sense and am marking as correct